# Switching between layouts from the same activity: Possible but recomended?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to know why do people keep recommending starting new Activities when you want to display another screen?

Let's say I want to display a screen with a label and an edit_text to ask for username, then another similar screen to ask for age, then another screen to display the data entered and ask for confirmation.

I did this:

```
main_layout.xml:   has a button let's say mainButton, onClick="startRegistration"
name_layout.xml:      edittext asking for name
age_layout.xml:        edittext asking for age
confirm_layout.xml:    display info + button to confirm
```

and in:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

onCreate(...) {
   ...
   setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
}

public void startRegistration(View clickedButton) {
   setContentView(R.layout.name_layout);
}
..
}
```

... and so on, all button handlers are public void methods in main class and each method contains `setContentView()` with the next layout as parameter.

I have a feeling this is bad programming style, however it works perfectly fine. Is it ok to do this? If not, is there any other easy way? Starting a new activity for such things feels really stupid to me.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you group 'activities' together in an Activity. For you, registration uses multiple screens but are linked to each other. I would suggest using 1 Activity with a ViewFlipper.

Having 1 Activity for all will screw up the navigation for the user. The Back key has to be handled specially. "if back key, set this content, else set this content, etc"

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't really read my questions, but thanks anyway!

Comment: I see there has been an Edit. I was responding to: "why do people keep recommending starting new Activities when you want to display another screen?"

Answer (score 0):

If you code different layouts for the same type of screen then its not really an ideal idea. The better idea is to have the same layout and point to the same layout from the classes where the layouts are the same. In the screen where you want to have an extra/less control or different control then just have unique IDs to such controls.

Refer the controls from their IDs and you will have a single layout file. Writing different layout classes where the controls are same will pave way to code repetition and hence is not an ideal way of coding.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the last paragraph makes sense but what I wrote is just an example, in my project the layouts are much more complicated and completely different (message displays, buttons, images), but they do simple things, just like moving through a game's menu (settings, credits, new game etc).

Comment: If the layout functionalities are different and there is no much resemblance between the controls being used in the layouts then you can use only one layout. But if there are multiple changes in the controls and all then its preferable to use different layouts. Single layout is used when most of the controls are common and some controls are different. But if many controls are different and the changes are multiple then its always suggested to use multiple layout files.